# Interactively select the price by using clicks

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

Can we interactively select price and time in the chart.
I can use the price and time as following and it let me do it for the first time:

```
price1_val = input.price(0, "Price 1", inline="price", confirm=true)
price1_time = input.time(0, "Time", inline="price", confirm=true)
```

However, for every new selection/click I have to open the indicator another time.

Is there a way that somehow I can only use the indicator once and everytime I want to select a new price/time I can do it on the same indicator?